# Use log() method on any string, and print the string to console

Tags: javascript

Once, at the job interview I had a task - I needed to make code from example to print the string to the console, in this example the string is "lorem ipsum".
If you add any string, and call log() on it, like in the example - it'll print the string to the console. Any ideas how to implement this?

```
"lorem ipsum".log()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `log` to `String.prototype`, that way all strings will have that method:

```
String.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log(this.toString());         // 'this' will be an instance of String which is an object, just use 'toString' to print as a string primitive value
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
String.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
}

"Hello world".log();

let str = "Another string";
str.log();
```

Comment: @user13949633 this isn't exclusive to strings, any type you want to add methods to, just add them to that type constructor's prototype

Comment: At the interview, I knew that - this task was something to do with inheritance. Now, I know for sure.